# Can we simplify the if-zero condition

Tags: google-sheets

I want to check if the formula produce 0 nor not. If the output value is NOT 0 then let it be , but if it's 0 then change it to "" (empty string).

When using if(), i have to type the formula twice: **if(formula<>0, formula, "")** .Is there any builtin function like **ifzero()** which similar to **ifna()** and **iferror()**

for example in **ifna()** i only need to type the formula once : **ifna(formula, "")**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind any time you are sharing a formula that we can't see what you are seeing. So while things may make perfect sense to you (who *can* see everything), it's a bit spotty for those of us "out here." For this reason, it is usually best to share a link to a sample spreadsheet with a small set of realistic data.

That said, I'll give it a go, sight unseen. Try this:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(1/(1/MMULT(if(AD99:BY2907="",0,AD99:BY2907), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(AD:BY),1,1,0)))))`

Where `MMULT` returns a non-zero number 1/(1/#) will equal the original number. But where `MMULT` returns 0, the division of 1/0 will cause an error, which `IFERROR` will return as null here.

I also tightened up the elements of the `MMULT` parameters, particularly the `IF` clause, which was unnecessarily complicated.

**ADDENDUM** (based on poster comment of 7/14)

If the result of the formula for each cell in the range will only ever be some number, null, or an error, the same structure holds true:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(1/(1/your-base-formula)))`

Comment: Sorry the formula is actually does't matter here. Only any random formula. The question is about when using if() , you have to type the formula twice. First in the condition parameter ,second in either the 2nd or 3drd parameter. Btw i've edited my question/post to simplify it.

Comment: See the addendum to my post above. The IFERROR is a form of IF, and the 1/(1/ serves to either trigger it or not trigger it, just as happens in a regular IF.